# Is it possible to add session variable in Startup class in ASP.Net 5?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to add Session variable when application starts, but not sure if this is possible?

```
 private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private ISession _session => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor ses)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = ses;
        _session.SetInt32("User", 1);
    }
```

I'm getting error for _httpContextAccessor:

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

I have used the example from [here](http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. If you want to have a session you need a browser making a request. A session is created when a request comes in. When the application starts there is no user making a request yet.

If you want to create add a session variable you can do this in methods like OnActionExecuting which you should then override in your controller. Take a look at this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609(v=vs.98).aspx